# "Modifier 'private' not allowed here" - why not?

Tags: java

I want to know why this problem occurs.

```
public class Sorter {

    public static char[] selectSort(String targetStr) {

        private char[] charArray = new char[targetStr.length()];
```

The problem occurs when the variable charArray is made private and there is a message:

> Modifier 'private' not allowed here.

Can anyone explain to me thoroughly why this happens so that I can better handle them in the future?

Comment: What would be the purpose of access modifier like `private` describing local variable? These variables are hidden from world already (they are accessible only inside block they ware declared in).

Comment: The asker has simply failed to adhere to the Java language syntax.

Answer (score 9):

You can't have access modifiers to method local variables.

All the method local variables are visible only inside the method.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use access modifiers with fields declared within method scope (i.e. local fields).

So neither `private` nor `public` nor `protected`.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) is a tutorial on Java variables that broaches the subject.

Answer (score 3):

That char array(`charArray` ) is already local to that method., You cannot access that outside of that method anyway. So access modifier doesn't make sense there.

Answer (score 2):

Scope of that variable is only till that method it cant be used outside that so there is no need to give access specifier to it.

Any variable created inside a method is local to that method only and it cant be accesed outside.

Scope of that variable `char Array` is only till that method it cant be used outside that so there is no need to give access specifier to it.